# Isolated singularites of $f(z)=\frac{\log(1+z)}{z^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the holomorphic function given by $$f(z)=\frac{\log(1+z)}{z^2}.$$

I know that $z_0=0$ is a pole of degree $1$.

My question: What about those points where the complex logarithm is not defined? E. g. $z_1=-1$. Is that also a singularity, if so, what kind of singularity is it and why?

Thank you!

Comment: The point $-1$ (and also the point $\infty$) are "branch points".  They may not be considered isolated singularities.  Check the technical definition of "isolated singularity" in your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points are no isolated singularities since it is a complete half line that must be removed. Hence you can't use the classification "removable/polar/essential" singularities for them.

The usuel denomination is branch point. We say that $]-\infty,-1]$ is the principal branch cut (since it is determined by the principal argument) of $\log(1+z)$. See here for more informations : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point.

Answer (score 0):

Well the function is differentiable near -1, so yes it has a singularity there. A holomorphic function can only have the following isolated singularities: poles, removable singularities, or neither which are so called essential singularities. It can also have a branch point, which is the case here because the function is discontinuous around a small circle centered around $z=-1$ (why?). It's more proper name is a logarithmic branch point.